# Python object proxy problem: descriptors and @staticmethod

Tags: python, static-methods, proxy-classes, python-descriptors

I'm trying to create a proxy (wrapper) object so I can modify behaviour of an already instantiated object. Attributes of a wrapper class are set to a newly generated class (using `type`) along with attributes of an underlying object, it's done this way because Python __magic __ methods work correctly only if they are members of a class. So `cls` is a wrapper class, `client` is the underlying object:

```
def __new__(cls, client, *args, **kwargs):
    ns = {}
    for i, attr in inspect.getmembers(client):
        if i in ('__init__', '__new__', '__getattribute__', '__dict__'):
            continue
        ns[i] = attr
    for i in cls.__dict__:
        if i in ('__new__',):
            continue
        elif i == '__init__':
            ns['_init_'] = getattr(cls, i)
            continue
        attr = getattr(cls, i)
        ns[i] = attr
    P = type(cls.__name__ + "." + client.__class__.__name__,
             (Proxy2.BaseProxy,), ns)
    P._client_ = client
    return P(*args, **kwargs)
```

The problem comes from `@staticmethod`/`@classmethod` in the wrapper class. I cannot call static method from an instance because `self` is being passed to it. I've tried to use `__get__` but without success. Here's a minimal example which fails:

```
class SuperA:
    @staticmethod
    def static():
        return 'static?'

class A:
    def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        v = object.__getattribute__(self, attr)
        if hasattr(v, '__get__'):
            v2 = v.__get__(None, self)
            return v2
        return v

A.static = getattr(SuperA, "static")
print(A.static())  # success
print(A().static())  # fail
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `getattr` which invokes descriptors mechanism `inspect.getattr_static` can be used like this:

```
A.static = inspect.getattr_static(SuperA, "static")
```